# Deselect listbox item in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am using listboxes in a windows phone application code written in c#.

```
<Grid>
<ListBox x:Name ="gsecList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="ShowGsecDetails">
```

**Event Handler :**

```
private void ShowGsecDetails(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string indexCode = gsecList.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/contactDetail.xaml?type=gsec&index="+indexCode, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

I am using the eventhandler `listBox1.SelectionChanged` to navigate to some other page depending on the selection made by the user. Now when I navigate back to the page again I see the listITem still selected. How can I deselect that item? I tried to use `listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1`. But that seemed to call up the selectionChanged event handler.

Comment: you could just handle when the `SelectedIndex == -1` and then not continue...

Comment: @SecretSquirrel thanks. I am going to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks but I think you might want to look at "Anirudh" answer as that may be a cleaner way of deselecting items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either do `ListBox1.UnselectAll()` or `ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1`

But in the second case you have to put a breakpoint in the `SelectionChanged` event handler to see if index is -1 (in that case don't execute the code). Hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

You can call [UnselectAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.unselectall.aspx) method

```
listBox1.UnselectAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnNavigatedTo` and set `null` as selected item.